# Transaction stays in capture queue

Tags: oracle, replication, oracle-11g, oracle-streams

I set up simple bidirectional db replication using Oracle Streams. I used enterprise manager for this. Streams are active and their status is ok. The problem is that the replication is very slow. What happened:

1. I made insert into on machine A.
2. I checked but there was no data in machine B.
3. I opened View Capture Statistics on machine A and my transaction was under Active Streams Transactions List (Running for more than 1 minute) and was Active For over 1000 seconds.
4. I went to make some food and when I came back transaction had been eventually propagated to machine B.

So it looks like the transaction stayed in some kind of buffer for over 1000 seconds. How can I speed up this process? I am totally new in databases so please forgive me if it is a stupid question :).

Machines are just vbox instances (WinXP + Oracle 11g Enterprise).

Greetings.

Comment: I did another insert and at this moment it lasts over 9000 seconds (literally about 9200) in this Active Streams Transactions List. What should I do?

Comment: Ok, I resolved the issue. I use sqlplus and I forgot to commit after insert into. That's why it did not replicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using sqlplus and I forgot to commit the changes. Before the commit, changes appeared only in the source database, but after I had committed them, the destination database got the new data.